# Server Crashed not figure it out from Dump file exact issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

Please find Dump File Details below.

```
STACK_COMMAND:  ** Pseudo Context ** ManagedPseudo ** Value: ffffffff ** ; kb



FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {3e208ee9-054a-52e2-32ae-f0feccff28c0}
STACK_TEXT:  
3b2b328c 6d1dbaf2 mscorlib_ni!System.Globalization.TextInfo.ToUpper+0x22
3b2b329c 6d1dbac4 mscorlib_ni!System.String.ToUpper+0x24
3b2b32a8 69df11d5 System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlTypeSystem+ProviderBase.<Parse>b__0+0x21
3b2b32b0 6bdcdc23 System_Core_ni!System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].MoveNext+0x43
3b2b32c0 6bdcddfe System_Core_ni!System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]]+0xee
3b2b32f8 6bdc510c System_Core_ni!System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]]+0x8c
3b2b3318 69defb19 System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlTypeSystem+ProviderBase.Parse+0x231
3b2b3348 69d78f26 System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFactory.Default+0x36
3b2b3358 69d7890b System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFactory.Member+0x2f
3b2b3374 69d70f59 System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Translator.BuildProjectionInternal+0x1f5
3b2b33d4 69d6fc96 System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Translator.BuildProjection+0x6e
3b2b345c 69d6fc01 System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Translator.BuildDefaultQuery+0x10d
3b2b3484 69d7ca56 System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.TranslateConstantTable+0x66
3b2b349c 69d7ab1b System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.CoerceToSequence+0x5f
3b2b34b4 69d7c194 System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere+0x24
3b2b34d0 69d81d59 System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall+0xfe1
3b2b3998 69d804fe System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall+0x42
3b2b39c4 69d7a5bc System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner+0x3fc
3b2b39f8 69d7c188 System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere+0x18
3b2b3a14 69d81d59 System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall+0xfe1
3b2b3edc 69d804fe System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall+0x42
3b2b3f08 69d7a5bc System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner+0x3fc
3b2b3f3c 69d7c188 System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere+0x18
3b2b3f58 69d81d59 System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall+0xfe1
3b2b4420 69d804fe System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall+0x42
3b2b444c 69d7a5bc System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner+0x3fc
3b2b4480 69d7c188 System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere+0x18
3b2b449c 69d81d59 System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall+0xfe1
3b2b4964 69d804fe System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall+0x42
3b2b4990 69d7a5bc System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner+0x3fc
3b2b49c4 69d7ef2c System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitOrderBy+0x6c
3b2b49ec 69d832dc System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall+0x2564
3b2b4eb4 69d804fe System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall+0x42
3b2b4ee0 69d7a5bc System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner+0x3fc
3b2b4f14 69d7f0a8 System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitThenBy+0x6c
3b2b4f38 69d834d6 System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall+0x275e
3b2b5400 69d804fe System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall+0x42
3b2b542c 69d7a5bc System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner+0x3fc
3b2b5460 69d7a0f6 System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.ConvertOuter+0x66
3b2b5474 69dd2d3b System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery+0x73
3b2b5490 69dd28ad System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute+0x85
3b2b54b8 69d92d3a System_Data_Linq_ni!System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator+0x22
3b2b54c8 6d1dfc82 mscorlib_ni!System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]]..ctor+0x172
3b2b54fc 6bdcfe0b System_Core_ni!System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]]+0x3b
3b2b5510 09329a13 I2.Web.dll!Unknown+0x673
3b2b5698 09328097 I2.Web.dll!Unknown+0xdf
3b2b5718 6b8e9d41 System_Web_Extensions_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceView.OnSelecting+0x5d
3b2b572c 6b8e948d System_Web_Extensions_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceView.GetSource+0x89
3b2b5758 6b8e925c System_Web_Extensions_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect+0x40
3b2b578c 6f7ec2ee System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select+0x16
3b2b579c 6f829d2f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect+0x8b
3b2b57b0 6f0ea90f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind+0x1f
3b2b57bc 6f86b705 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind+0x5
3b2b57c0 6f0bd3da System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound+0x6a
3b2b57e0 6f9dc5a2 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.set_RequiresDataBinding+0x968922
3b2b57f0 6f868ce2 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.set_PageIndex+0x3a
3b2b5800 0d3b2045 I2.Web.dll!Unknown+0x3d
3b2b581c 0d3b1e5a I2.Web.dll!Unknown+0x12a
3b2b58a8 6fa0706f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnDataBound+0x91c6ff
3b2b58bc 6f829f3e System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback+0x96
3b2b58cc 6f7ec2fa System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select+0x22
3b2b58dc 6f829d2f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect+0x8b
3b2b58f0 6f0ea90f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind+0x1f
3b2b58fc 6f86b705 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind+0x5
3b2b5900 6f0bd3da System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound+0x6a
3b2b5920 6f9dc5a2 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.set_RequiresDataBinding+0x968922
3b2b5930 6f868ce2 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.set_PageIndex+0x3a
3b2b5940 0d3b2045 I2.Web.dll!Unknown+0x3d
3b2b595c 0d3b1e5a I2.Web.dll!Unknown+0x12a
3b2b59e8 6fa0706f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnDataBound+0x91c6ff
3b2b59fc 6f829f3e System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback+0x96
3b2b5a0c 6f7ec2fa System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select+0x22
3b2b5a1c 6f829d2f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect+0x8b
3b2b5a30 6f0ea90f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind+0x1f
3b2b5a3c 6f86b705 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind+0x5
3b2b5a40 6f0bd3da System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound+0x6a
3b2b5a60 6f9dc5a2 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.set_RequiresDataBinding+0x968922
3b2b5a70 6f868ce2 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.set_PageIndex+0x3a
3b2b5a80 0d3b2045 I2.Web.dll!Unknown+0x3d
3b2b5a9c 0d3b1e5a I2.Web.dll!Unknown+0x12a
3b2b5b28 6fa0706f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnDataBound+0x91c6ff
3b2b5b3c 6f829f3e System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback+0x96
3b2b5b4c 6f7ec2fa System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select+0x22
3b2b5b5c 6f829d2f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect+0x8b
3b2b5b70 6f0ea90f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind+0x1f
3b2b5b7c 6f86b705 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind+0x5
3b2b5b80 6f0bd3da System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound+0x6a
3b2b5ba0 6f9dc5a2 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.set_RequiresDataBinding+0x968922
3b2b5bb0 6f868ce2 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.set_PageIndex+0x3a
3b2b5bc0 0d3b2045 I2.Web.dll!Unknown+0x3d
3b2b5bdc 0d3b1e5a I2.Web.dll!Unknown+0x12a
3b2b5c68 6fa0706f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnDataBound+0x91c6ff
3b2b5c7c 6f829f3e System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback+0x96
3b2b5c8c 6f7ec2fa System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select+0x22
3b2b5c9c 6f829d2f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect+0x8b
3b2b5cb0 6f0ea90f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind+0x1f
3b2b5cbc 6f86b705 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind+0x5
3b2b5cc0 6f0bd3da System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound+0x6a
3b2b5ce0 6f9dc5a2 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.set_RequiresDataBinding+0x968922
3b2b5cf0 6f868ce2 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.set_PageIndex+0x3a
3b2b5d00 0d3b2045 I2.Web.dll!Unknown+0x3d
3b2b5d1c 0d3b1e5a I2.Web.dll!Unknown+0x12a
3b2b5da8 6fa0706f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnDataBound+0x91c6ff
3b2b5dbc 6f829f3e System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback+0x96
3b2b5dcc 6f7ec2fa System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select+0x22
3b2b5ddc 6f829d2f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect+0x8b
3b2b5df0 6f0ea90f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind+0x1f
3b2b5dfc 6f86b705 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind+0x5
3b2b5e00 6f0bd3da System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound+0x6a
3b2b5e20 6f9dc5a2 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.set_RequiresDataBinding+0x968922
3b2b5e30 6f868ce2 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.set_PageIndex+0x3a
3b2b5e40 0d3b2045 I2.Web.dll!Unknown+0x3d
3b2b5e5c 0d3b1e5a I2.Web.dll!Unknown+0x12a
3b2b5ee8 6fa0706f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnDataBound+0x91c6ff
3b2b5efc 6f829f3e System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback+0x96
3b2b5f0c 6f7ec2fa System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select+0x22
3b2b5f1c 6f829d2f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect+0x8b
3b2b5f30 6f0ea90f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind+0x1f
3b2b5f3c 6f86b705 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind+0x5
3b2b5f40 6f0bd3da System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound+0x6a
3b2b5f60 6f9dc5a2 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.set_RequiresDataBinding+0x968922
3b2b5f70 6f868ce2 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.set_PageIndex+0x3a
3b2b5f80 0d3b2045 I2.Web.dll!Unknown+0x3d
3b2b5f9c 0d3b1e5a I2.Web.dll!Unknown+0x12a
3b2b6028 6fa0706f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnDataBound+0x91c6ff
3b2b603c 6f829f3e System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback+0x96
3b2b604c 6f7ec2fa System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select+0x22
3b2b605c 6f829d2f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect+0x8b
3b2b6070 6f0ea90f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind+0x1f
3b2b607c 6f86b705 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind+0x5
3b2b6080 6f0bd3da System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound+0x6a
3b2b60a0 6f9dc5a2 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.set_RequiresDataBinding+0x968922
3b2b60b0 6f868ce2 System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.set_PageIndex+0x3a
3b2b60c0 0d3b2045 I2.Web.dll!Unknown+0x3d
3b2b60dc 0d3b1e5a I2.Web.dll!Unknown+0x12a
3b2b6168 6fa0706f System_Web_ni!System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnDataBound+0x91c6ff
3b2b617c 6f829f3e Syst
```

Comment: Probably you have missed error message and which technologies are used. LINQ to SQL?

Comment: Linq to Sql after server crash getting Dump file only. Unable to find exact issue of server down

Comment: Asp.net application

Comment: Something with `ToUpper` ;) Probably cannot translate to SQL.

Comment: Sometimes this issue happening not everytime. And one more hints grid binding repeatedly happening. I don't think ToUpper will be the cause

Comment: If  it  happens sometimes, it can be multithreading issue. Not enough information for help.